# python: How to delete every character after a specific character in a string?

Tags: python

I have to filter a string variable by removing every character after 'U'.

For example:

1) having 075600U2

I should get 075600U

2)
having 892009U24

I should get 892009U

I tried to do a for loop to replace every character after U as '' but I'm not getting any result

```
    material = '075600U2'

    for i in range((material.find('U')+1), len(material)):
        material[i].replace('')

    print(material)
```

I expect the output of '075600U', but the actual output is '075600U2'

Any idea?

Comment: `''.join(material.partition("U")[:2])`

Answer (score 1):

```
In [34]: material = '075600U2'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

In [35]: ''.join(material.partition("U")[:2])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[35]: '075600U'

In [36]: material = '075600U258'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

In [37]: ''.join(material.partition("U")[:2])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[37]: '075600U'

In [38]: material = '075600'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [39]: ''.join(material.partition("U")[:2])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[39]: '075600'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `re.sub` function comes in handy here:

```
material = '075600U2'
output = re.sub(r'(?<=U).*', '', material)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
075600U
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *replacing* those characters, why not just slice them off?

```
material = material[:material.find('U')+1]
```

Comment: this work perfectly and without for loops. So for the data analysis it will save a lot of running time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import re 
replaced = re.sub('U[\d]*', 'U', material) 
print(replaced)
```

output

```
075600U
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html